# A Firebug Net Panel for IE?

Tags: performance, internet-explorer, firebug, ie-developer-tools, page-load-time

What are the alternatives on IE 8 that can work like the [Firebug Net Panel](http://getfirebug.com/network)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides using the developer preview of IE9, you can use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/).

Comment: Fiddler is the only choice? (if not using IE 9 preview)